# WPF Treeview from database

Tags: wpf, datatable, treeview

i have just started looking at mvvm and WPF recently and Ive been looking over Josh Smiths article on treeview and i think i understand how to implement it. the issue i have been having is this part

```
        public static Person GetFamilyTree()
    {
        // In a real app this method would access a database.
        return new Person
        {
            Name = "David Weatherbeam",
            Children =
            {
                new Person
                {
                    Name="Alberto Weatherbeam",
                    Children=
                    {
                        new Person
                        {
                            Name="Zena Hairmonger",
                            Children=
                            {
                                new Person
                                {
                                    Name="Sarah Applifunk",
                                }
                            }
                        },

    public class Person
{
    readonly List<Person> _children = new List<Person>();
    public IList<Person> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

i have a database tables as followed

ID Tool

reportID ReportName ToolID

i was just wanting to know how i would change this hard coded approach into loading it dynamically.

any help would be appeaciated

Thanks,

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the database? It does not look so, that the db has anything to do with your coding. Your coding is about names and families, but your database about tools? How does this fit together?

Comment: yeah sorry, the sample code is from josh smiths article on code project. essentially the reports will be the children of the tools

Comment: Refer the article by me if you Entity Framework. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21068.wpf-treeview-using-self-reference-table-and-entity-framework.aspx